Value of $k$ that gives the highest Restricted-Part Integer Partition Number for $n$
Let $p_k(n)$ be the number of possible partitions of an Integer $n$ into exactly $k$ parts. We know that for any given $n$, $p_k(n)$ gives a non-zero result for $0<k\leq n$, and that the size of this result equals $1$ for $k=1$, peaks at certain value of $k$ and then falls back down to eventually equal $1$ at $n=k$.
A question that I've been trying to find but haven't been able to find an answer for is whether there is a known way to determine what value of $k$ in $p_k(n)$ gives the highest value for a given $n$. Doing my own calculations, I do know that for lower values of $n$, there can be multiple values of $k$ that gives the highest value of $p_k(n)$:



$n$
$k$ for greatest $p_k(n)$
greatest $p_k(n)$




0
0
1


1
1
1


2
{1,2}
1


3
{1,2,3}
1


4
2
2


5
{2,3}
3


6
{2,3}
4


7
3
5


8
{3,4}
5


9
3
7


10
4
9



So if the question is made easier, let us define the question as: Is there a way (either an explicit formula or some other easily computable system) that allows us to find the lowest value of $k$ which outputs the highest $p_k(n)$ for a given $n$ without having to calculate $p_k(n)$ for all values of $k$?
I'd already written a python program to calculate all values of $p_k(n)$ up to $n=1000$, and looking at the list of entries, it doesn't appear to be a linear relationship, and the growth rate of the highest $k$ seems to slow down as $n$ increases:



$n$
$k$ for greatest $p_k(n)$
greatest $p_k(n)$




15
5
30


20
6
90


25
7
248


50
11
17475


100
19
10885999


150
26
1901740434


200
28
158042231843


300
37
295234632551509


400
45
183605649560519658


500
52
55664213538686024350


600
58
10050783969822373611058


700
64
1219762447262799701217269


800
70
107842050411184264551268279


900
76
7344191693292687266476027566


1000
81
401779428811641224675190768242



It looks like it could be logarithmic, but nothing I've tried has managed to give any better insight than that. Is this a solved question that I just haven't been able to find?

https://oeis.org/A026819 is the sequence.

Good to know that the sequence is known (there's even two basically equivalent sequences!), but neither entry has any further information on an actual relationship!
